# how to set JSP+Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I'm a beginner for JSP,about six months ago I learned php,now ,i want to try jsp.My question is :when i set my native jsp development envoriment(tomcat+java+mysql),and i can open tomcat in my 8080 port.But when i put my project(download from github,a jsp framework),i couldn't open the project throw localhost:8080/projectname....but the jsp project's readme told me,the index page can be visited just after put the project in tomcat's webapps folder. Now,tomcat just show 404 to me. I also put the project up to my server,my server is a auto jsp envoriment,when i try to open my project throw my browser,it's just blank.
PS:i'm chinese,my english is not very good!But i have tried my best to tell the details.

Comment: Please consider formatting the text in your post. It's very hard to read it the way it is now.

Comment: Thanks ,i will notice it now time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should package the project as war and then keep it in webapps folder.

Comment: thanks ,and can you tell me how?can I do it use eclipse?

Comment: yes, right click->export-> dynamic web proj->war file. Choose the path where you want to save in local machine and then copy. This is for development purpose only, and the same can be done with maven and ant. Please refer to any documentation related to web project packaging. Happy coding

Comment: please accept the response if it helped you. Happy coding